# validation with sent and bounces

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I have a validation issue with my sends and DE count. I have around 1M emails in a campaign send, off which there are 32K in bounced,8K in exclusions and the total emails sent are only 903K. i'm unable to trace the remaining emails ( 1000-903-32-8_) = 57K emails.

All the records are in active status and not unsubscribed.
I have checked the deduplication during send and also in the DE there are no duplicate records. its a simple manual send. Is there  any easy way to get the missing records details.

Thank you
Vinay

Comment: well each record in bounce would be in sent, you should run the not sent extract to see why the subscriber was not sent to

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to pull a NotSent tracking extract:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000313980&type=1

If you're feeling daring and your data-set is small, you can also retrieve [NotSentEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/notsentevent.html) data using the SOAP API.

Example SOAP body:

```xml
<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>NotSentEvent</ObjectType>
        <Properties>EventDate</Properties>
        <Properties>EventType</Properties>
        <Properties>SendID</Properties>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        <Properties>TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>EventDate</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>greaterThan</SimpleOperator>
            <DateValue>2021-12-29T04:42:01.063Z</DateValue>
        </Filter>
    </RetrieveRequest>
</RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

You can modify the filter to use whatever criteria you need.  Object properties are [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/notsentevent.html).

Example response:

```xml
<RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
    <RequestID>123</RequestID>
    <Results xsi:type="NotSentEvent">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
        <SendID>634623</SendID>
        <SubscriberKey>test@example.com</SubscriberKey>
        <EventDate>2021-12-29T14:41:02.067Z</EventDate>
        <EventType>NotSent</EventType>
        <TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID />
    </Results>
</RetrieveResponseMsg>
```